# How do you kill a Sway session from a virtual console?

Tags: sway

I can start a Sway session from a virtual console by just giving the command "sway" while in user mode, however, it is not clear how to cleanly kill the session from a virtual console. There is no mention of how to kill a Sway session either in the sway manpage or the swaymsg manpage.

The following command does not work:

```
swaymsg exit
```

The error is "Unable to retrieve socket path" which is apparently because I am in the second virtual console and the Sway session is in the first virtual console.

There is no way to get to a terminal (Logo+Return) because I do not have alacritty installed, and the key binding tries to start alacritty.

I also tried Logo+Shift+e to exit the session but it pops up a warning message with a button and there is apparently no way to activate the button from the keyboard and I do not have a mouse installed in this particular computer.

I tried to shift the focus to the "Yes" button in the exit warning by using the Logo+arrow keys combination, but that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the swaymsg man page:

```
*-s, --socket* <path>
    Use the specified socket path. Otherwise, swaymsg will ask sway where the
    socket is (which is the value of $SWAYSOCK, then of $I3SOCK).
```

The default socket path is not really documented, but can be found in the code at https://github.com/swaywm/sway/blob/d77247117c6f6ebd637a3b4ac029015381de5466/sway/ipc-server.c#L138-L146: It's either `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/sway-ipc.<numeric-userid>.<pid-of-sway>.sock` or `/tmp/sway-ipc.<numeric-userid>.<pid-of-sway>.sock`.

Alternatively, install alacritty in the terminal that you still have access to.